# Proof of an analogue of Lagrange's Theorem for profinite groups

Tags: group-theory, profinite-groups

I have been trying to work through a proof for Lagrange's theorem extended to profinite groups from John Wilson's book.

The statement of the theorem is "for $H$ and $K$ subgroups of a profinite group $G$, such that $K\leq H \leq G$ then $\lvert G:K\rvert=\lvert G:H\rvert \cdot \lvert H:K\rvert$.

The proof begins by stating that if $N\triangleleft_O G$ is an open normal subgroup then $$\lvert G:NK\rvert=\lvert G:NH\rvert \cdot \lvert NH:NK\rvert=\lvert G:NH\rvert \cdot \lvert H:(N\cap H)K\rvert$$
and $N\cap H\triangleleft_O G$.

I follow the proof up until here but the bit which gets me is that it then says that therefore $\lvert G:K\rvert$ divides $\lvert G:H\rvert \cdot \lvert H:K\rvert$. I believe this has something to do with a previous definition that the index of a subgroup $H\leq G$ for a profinite group $G$

Answer (score 0):

As you supposed correctly, this argument just makes use of the definition of the index of a closed subgroup $H$ of a profinite group $G$: By definition,

$|G:H|=lcm\{G:NH\mid N\unlhd_O G\}$.

As you showed, for any $N\unlhd_O G$, $|G:NK|$ divides $|G:NH|\cdot |H:\tilde{N}K|$ for some $\tilde{N}\unlhd_O H$; so $|G:H|$ divides $lcm(|G:NH|\cdot |H:\tilde{N}K|: N\unlhd_O G,\:\tilde{N}\unlhd_O H)$ which by definition divides $|G:H|\cdot|H:K|$.